# CSS submenu hide behind content in Blogger

Tags: css, blogger

I searched the Net, found similar issue, but after trying all solutions, I failed to fix the issue.

In the website below, each menu item with '+' has submenu, same thing works at another blogger blog.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this code

```
.tabs-outer{
overflow:hidden;
```

}

with

```
.tabs-outer{
overflow:visible;
```

}